# increasing display brightness on vaio laptop fedora 9

Tags: fedora, brightness

I have fedora 9 on sony vaio with dual boot. But Fn keys dont work. Is there any other way to adjust brightness ? I have ATI graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xgamma`:

```
xgamma -gamma 2.0
```

default is 1.0, anything higher will brighten the output from the X server (not the laptop's backlight though) so it shouldn't use more battery.

Answer (score 0):

Try spicctrl, which is at least present in the F11 repos: 
[spicctrl](http://popies.net/sonypi/)
[sony-laptop](http://www.linux.it/~malattia/wiki/index.php/Sony_drivers)

I don't have a VAIO, so can't comment on spicctrl in action.

Also, not sure about F9, but rpmfind turns up (for i386):
[F9 i386 rpm](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/9/i386/spicctrl-1.9-6.fc9.i386.html)